# HTML5 PostMessage Cross-Domain Issue

Tags: html, cross-domain, postmessage

I am attempting to use the HTML5 method 'postMessage'.  I know this method only works in 'modern' browsers, but for my customer base, that is good enough.

Here is my situation:
A browser window on domain 'abc.com' opens a new window on domain 'xyz.com'.  I own both domains, and I can put any javascript I need to on either side.  From what I can tell, I should be able to use 'postMessage' to send messages between the two windows.  This works in Chrome, but not in IE 9.  I am unable to get a reference to the parent window from the child or vice-versa.  If both windows are on the same domain, I do not have a problem.

So, is this a bug ("feature") of IE's implementation of 'postMessage'?  Is there any way I can accomplish what I am trying to do?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you post a link, or the code you're using?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, [IE's `postMessage` implementation only works between windows and iframes and frames](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/16/bugs-in-ie8-support-for-html5-postmessage-sessionstorage-and-localstorage.aspx).  Trying it with a `window.open` will result in a `No such interface` error when `postMessage` is called, even though the debugger clearly shows the method existing.